# Selenium не находит элемент по Xpath, хотя он есть на странице

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Есть парсер для [сайта](https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Sticker%20%7C%20Ninjas%20in%20Pyjamas%20%7C%20Cologne%202014). Всё корректно работает за исключением поиска некоторых элементов по xpath. Имею следующий код:

```
count = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="market_commodity_forsale"]/span[1]')
```

Этот элемент есть (проверял через F12, скрин ниже), но в консоли получаю ошибку

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //div[@id="market_commodity_forsale"]/span[1]
```

Сайт с динамическим контентом, да и без xpath не вижу способов найти этот элемент. Надеюсь на помощь
Вот скрин:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл ответ. Сами xpath-ы были выстроены правильно, но что б наверняка, берите xpath значения с открытого браузера с помощью Selenium. Во вторых (то, что помогло мне) выставьте задержку между загрузкой страницы и поиском элементов. Я сделал с помощью модуля time функции sleep на 2 секунды.